# How can I use the AMS Euler font in plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, euler

I want to use the [AMS Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler) font designed by Zapf in my document. I looked for packages on CTAN (e.g., the [*euler* package](https://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/euler.pdf)), but they are specifically designed for LaTeX.

I took a look at the `gkpmac.tex` file [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) wrote from *Concrete Mathematics* and it is likely to contain the answer I am looking for, but I can't fully understand it and determine what lines to extract to an `eumac.tex` or `euler.tex` file (I don't know what the naming convention is in that case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this document, User's Guide to AMSFonts Version 2, https://texdoc.org/serve/amsfndoc.pdf/0, which helped guide the plain TeX implementation.  See section 5.1 on pp. 12-13.

In the MWE, I activate the fraktur and roman euler fonts, in both medium and bold.  Other euler font families (`eusm`, `eusb`, and `euex`) should follow the same approach, with different supported sizes for `euex`.

```
\input amssym
%\input amssym.def

\font\teneufm=eufm10
\font\seveneufm=eufm7
\font\fiveeufm=eufm5
\newfam\eufmfam
\textfont\eufmfam=\teneufm
\scriptfont\eufmfam=\seveneufm
\scriptscriptfont\eufmfam=\fiveeufm
\def\eufm#1{{\fam\eufmfam\relax#1}}

\font\teneufb=eufb10
\font\seveneufb=eufb7
\font\fiveeufb=eufb5
\newfam\eufbfam
\textfont\eufbfam=\teneufb
\scriptfont\eufbfam=\seveneufb
\scriptscriptfont\eufbfam=\fiveeufb
\def\eufb#1{{\fam\eufbfam\relax#1}}

\font\teneurm=eurm10
\font\seveneurm=eurm7
\font\fiveeurm=eurm5
\newfam\eurmfam
\textfont\eurmfam=\teneurm
\scriptfont\eurmfam=\seveneurm
\scriptscriptfont\eurmfam=\fiveeurm
\def\eurm#1{{\fam\eurmfam\relax#1}}

\font\teneurb=eurb10
\font\seveneurb=eurb7
\font\fiveeurb=eurb5
\newfam\eurbfam
\textfont\eurbfam=\teneurb
\scriptfont\eurbfam=\seveneurb
\scriptscriptfont\eurbfam=\fiveeurb
\def\eurb#1{{\fam\eurbfam\relax#1}}

$$\eufm{XYZ} = \eufb{XYZ} = \eurm{xyz} = \eurb{xyz}$$
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't understand why you are importing the `amssym.def` file since you are writing the definitions below

Comment: @Laravel It is because I stumbled into the answer piecemeal (and don't work often in Plain TeX).  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No problem, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [mtbe](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/mtbe) on CTAN that was created for the book *Mathematical TeX by Example* by Arvind Borde to use the AMS Euler fonts together with the Concrete fonts.

```
\input eulconc
```

License:

> The six files in the MTBE package may be copied, distributed and used freely.

Note that it also defines a lot of (imho irrelevant) other macros:

```
...
\def\adj{\relbar\joinrel\relbar} % adjacent in a graph
\let\<=\langle \let \>=\rangle
\def\Pr{\mathop{\rm Pr}\nolimits}
\def\Mean{\mathop{\rm Mean}\nolimits}
\def\Var{\mathop{\rm Var}\nolimits}
...
```